# How to ignore input string starting with '#' in c?

Tags: c, input

I am taking input from a file and reading a character but file contains some comments starting by # so i dont want to read these inputs. How to ignore these inputs in c. Is there any command like cin.ignore() in c to do this.
thanks

Comment: what is wrong in reading such a line and checking it for `#` in the first character(s)?

Comment: "I am taking input from a file and reading a character" --> post that C code.

Comment: Pretty strange question how to do nothing. Presumably when you read lines that don't start with #, you do something. Well, don't do that.

Comment: I am comparing char with i,e,d  only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILE * fp;
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;

fp = fopen("file", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    if (read > 0 && line[0] == '#')
        printf("ignored\n"); //ignore this line
    else if (read > 0)
        printf("%s", line);
}
```

Comment: And there's standard C [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) if you're on a non-POSIX system without `getline()`.